# How to flash a spark core from C#

Tags: c#, .net, sparkcore

I am trying to flash a spark core from a C# application.  I keep getting `{ error: Nothing to do? }` response.

Below is my code

```
var url = string.Format("https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/{0}", sparkDeviceID);

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accesstoken);
    using (var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        HttpContent fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(rom));
        //client.SendAsync()
        formData.Add(fileContent, "file", "file");
        var response = client.PutAsync(url, formData).Result;

        if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            throw new Exception("An error occurred during rom flash!");

        var responseStream = response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result;
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream, true))
        {
            var result = reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

The documentation reads:

> The API request should be encoded as multipart/form-data with a file field populated.

I believe the problem is the endpoint doesn't see the file.  Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: not sure, but I see you're using PutAsync. Have you tried PostAsync if there is an option (there may be an issue of using incorrect http verb)?

Comment: The verb required by the target api is PUT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got it working.

The issue was the way .NET generated the content-disposition header for the file form data.

I used fiddler to compare the output of a successful put request to the put request that my code was generating:

**Successful PUT request generated using CURL:**

```
PUT http://127.0.0.1:8888/ HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.33.0
Host: 127.0.0.1:8888
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 2861
Expect: 100-continue
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------5efcf64a370f13c8

--------------------------5efcf64a370f13c8
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="ms.ino"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

...
```

**My PUT request (unsuccessful):**

```
PUT https://api.spark.io/v1/devices/{deviceid} HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Bearer {access_token}
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary="135f5425-9342-4ffa-a645-99c04834026f"
Host: api.spark.io
Content-Length: 2878
Expect: 100-continue

--135f5425-9342-4ffa-a645-99c04834026f
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=file.ino; filename*=utf-8''file.ino

...
```

If you'll notice the difference in the Content-Type for the actual file being sent:

Successful: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="ms.ino"

Unsuccessful: Content-Disposition: form-data; name=file; filename=file.ino; filename*=utf-8''file.ino

Most specifically, the resolution was to add quotes around the `name` attribute.

**Resolution:**

```
formData.Add(fileContent, "\"file\"", "file.ino");
```